# Send Outlook Email Via Default Account

Tags: c#, outlook

**Hello**

How can I programmatically send Outlook Mail in C # through the default mail account when multiple mail accounts are configured?

**Thanks**

Comment: SO is not a free software writing website. Please post about a specific problem, include simplified sample code. Please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by default account?
If you want to sent by the account using the program and you have an exchange server you could use this:

```
    string exchangeServer;
    public void SendMail(string recipient, string subject, string body)
    {
        var service = CreateService(recipient);      
        EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = body;
        message.ToRecipients.Add(recipient);
        message.SendAndSaveCopy();
    }

    private ExchangeService CreateService(string recipient)
    {
        var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        service.Url = new Uri(exchangeServer);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(Credential.impersonateUser, Credential.impersonatePassword);
        service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, recipient);
        service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", recipient);
        return service;
    }
```